# Formatted hard disk drive not detected on two different enclosures/docking station

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, hardware-detection

I am facing a tricky problem with a hard disk drive detected as unformated while already formated. I made several permutations to try to identify the origin of the problem.

So here are the configurations:

- Computer **A**: HP Elitebook (laptop) / Windows 7 x64 pro
- Computer **B**: Not laptop / Windows 7 x64 pro
- Computer **C**: Toshiba (laptop) / Ubuntu 12.04 x64 LTS
- Hard disk drive enclosure **a**: Icy box [IB-116StU3-B](https://www.1000ordi.ch/icy-box-ib-116stu3-b-ib-116stu3-b-77350_en.pdf) (docking station)
- Hard disk drive enclosure **b**: Lian Li [ex-503](http://www.lian-li.com/en/dt_portfolio/ex-503/) (not used with any RAID mode)
- Hard disk drive **1**: [WD40EFRX](http://www.wdc.com/global/products/specs/?driveID=1324&language=1) (new one)
- Hard disk drive **2**: [WD20EARX](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-701229.pdf) (old one with data)

I want my new disk (Hard disk drive **1**, WD40EFRX) to work with all computers and all enclosures, and right now, it's not the case. For now:

- When I format disk **1** with computer **A**, **B** or **C** and enclosure **a**: the disk is readable with computers **A**, **B** and **C**, but only with enclosure **a** (not with enclosure **b**)
- When I format disk **1** with computer **A**, **B**, or **C** and enclosure **b**: the disk is readable with computers **A**, **B** and **C**, but only with enclosure **b** (not with enclosure **a**)

I tried to format with both MS-DOS (by default) and GPT partition table but with NTFS in all cases, and the result is the same.

I tried an old disk (Hard disk drive **2**, WD20EARX), that was formated on computer **B** with enclosure **b** year ago, and the disk work as expected on all computers with both enclosures **a** and **b**.

So the question is the following: what is the origin of the problem, and how to make Hard disk drive 1 to work normally?